# Converting a filename to md5 hash of the file

Tags: php, md5

I have a script I found for getting the md5 of a file name and then I use it to rename the file. But I realize that that is wrong and I need to actually get the md5 of the file not just it's name.

Wondering how you do that. Here is what I have currently:

```
function convertFileToMD5($filename) { 
    $filename_parts = explode('.',$filename);
    $count = count($filename_parts);
    if($count> 1) {
        $ext = $filename_parts[$count-1];
        unset($filename_parts[$count-1]);
        $filename_to_md5 =  implode('.',$filename_parts);
        $newName = md5($filename_to_md5). '.' . $ext ;
    } else {
        $newName = md5($filename);
    }        
    return $newName;
}
```

Which I use with this function

```
function uploadImage($image, $directory) {
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $image['name'];
    $file_size = $image['size'];
    $file_tmp = $image['tmp_name'];
    $file_type= $image['type'];   
    if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be under 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
    $newName = convertFileToMD5($file_name);
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$directory".$newName);
        $image = "$directory" . $newName;
        return $image;
    }else{
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the hash_file function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php

```
hash_file('md5', 'your_file.txt');
```

Or the more specific md5_file function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

```
md5_file('your_file.txt');
```